# Mouseleave event is not fired when element transformed

Tags: javascript, html, css

For instance, I have a block with `mouseenter`, `mouseleave` and `click` events. When I am clicking on the block it moves to the right while mouse pointer stays at the same place. After this mouseleave event is not fired. Yes, I know that CSS property `transform` changes only visual model of the element and actually doesn't move it. But maybe has any workaround to solve this problem without changing logic?

```js
const square = document.querySelector('.square');

square.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  square.style.background = '#00bb11';
});

square.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  square.style.background = '#ddd111';
});

square.addEventListener('click', () => {
  square.classList.toggle('moved');
});
```

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ddd111;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: #111;
}

.square.moved {
  transform: translateX(150px);
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
   Click
</div>
```

Comment: Probably not the most elegant solution but why not just setting `square.style.background = '#ddd111';` inside the click event too? `mouseout` listens to the mouse movement, but your are moving the element from under the mouse. Or you could use [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event) to check if the mouse is till on the element but that seems like an overkill to me

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? Can you give more background info?

Comment: @Keming, I need to call a callback function from mouseleave event (doesn't matter what it does) when a mouse pointer is not over the block.

Answer (score 0):

Could you fire the mouseleave event manually in the click handler?

```js
const square = document.querySelector('.square');

square.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  square.style.background = '#00bb11';
});

square.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  square.style.background = '#ddd111';
});

square.addEventListener('click', () => {
  square.classList.toggle('moved');
  var event = new Event('mouseout');
  square.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ddd111;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: #111;
}

.square.moved {
  transform: translateX(150px);
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
   Click
</div>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't suit me. Because on click event a cursor is still over the block.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just add

```
square.style.background = '#ddd111';
```

at the click event

```js
const square = document.querySelector('.square');

square.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  square.style.background = '#00bb11';
});

square.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  square.style.background = '#ddd111';
});

square.addEventListener('click', () => {
  square.style.background = '#ddd111';
  square.classList.toggle('moved');
});
```

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ddd111;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: #111;
}

.square.moved {
  transform: translateX(150px);
 
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
   Click
</div>
```